# container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library android-support-v7

Tags: android, eclipse

I know this question has been asked before, but I've done everything I could find on that issue and it still doesn't help.

It all started when I accidentally deleted the project folder from the Git workspace. 
Fortunately I had the project on some folder on the computer. I imported it but I keep on getting this error.

Thanks.